# «Секреты и советы по шитью»

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, однородные-члены

Режет слух оборот: "Секреты и советы по шитью..."
Проблема, кажется, в том, что некорректно говорить "секреты по чему-либо". Можно ли и нужно ли это исправлять?

Comment: Шитьё ("О шитье" - если статья, а не книжка): секреты и советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** Из "Справочника по правописанию и литературной правке" Д. Э. Розенталя ([§ 205. Управление при однородных членах предложения](https://tepka.ru/rozental_2/205.html)):

При двух или нескольких управляющих словах [«секреты» и «советы»] общее зависимое слово [«по шитью»] допустимо, когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа и предлога, например: *читать* [что?] *и конспектировать* [что?] *книгу; подбирать и готовить кадры; надеяться* [на что?] *и рассчитывать* [на что?] *на помощь.*

Наличие общего зависимого слова **при различном управлении** нарушает грамматико-стилистическую норму, например: *«с помощью и в сотрудничестве с местными организациями»* (ср. правильный вариант: с помощью местных организаций и в сотрудничестве с ними), *«организация* [чего?] *и руководство* [чем?] *стачечной борьбой»; «надеяться* [на что?] *и верить* [во что?] *в возможность».*

Изредка подобные конструкции встречаются у писателей, например: жмурил и хлопал глазами (Гоголь); ловя и избегая вопросительно устремленный на него взор Кати (Тургенев); препятствует или затягивает достижение соглашения (Эренбург).

**II.** В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[секрет](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Sekret-45233.html)
2. **чего**. Скрытая причина. *Секрет успеха. Постичь в чём секрет мастерства. Секрет молодости прост.*

В нашем случае правильное управление такое: секреты (чего? Р. п.) шитья и советы (по чему? Д. п.) по шитью.

Возможное оформление: «Шитьё. Секреты и советы»; [«Вязание: советы и секреты»](https://www.pinterest.ru/yuliakup5/%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B/).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Просто прекрасный ответ!

Comment: Благодарю. Рада, что смогла помочь.